# Adding up all combinations of number in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to write a program in javascript that gets an unspecified number of numbers out of a html textarea and tries all combinations (adding all numbers with eachother) to see if it mathches a number you specified.

Now I can make an array out of the string in the textarea and using `for` loops I add these up (see below code). The problem how can you do this for an unspecified number of numbers that are to be added up (e.g. adding up 7 different number if you enter 7 numbers in textarea)? I was thinking of using a second array and, which gets the numbers to add up out of the first loop. And then make te lenght of the loop variable by using a for loop with the lenght of the array containing all numbers (lines in my example) as endvalue.

How can I fill in the values of this 2nd array, making sure all combinations are used?

By the way, I wanted this code because I am a auditor. Sometimes a client reverses a couple of amounts in one booking, without any comment. This code will make it a lot easier to check what bookings have been reversed

edit: The awnser of cheeken seems to be working I only have one remark. What if multiple sub sets of your power set added up result in the number you are looking for? e.g.:findSum([1,2,3,4,5],6) can result [1,2,3] but also [2,4] or [1,5]. is it possible to let the function return multiple sub sets?

Found the answer my self :)
I replaced code

```
return numberSet;
```

By

```
document.getElementById("outp").value=document.getElementById("outp").value+ numberSet +"\n";
```

Thank you very much Cheeken

One more additional question. How do i format the input for parsing that function? The code below doesn't seem to work. inp is the ID of the textarea where the input is (the numbers are seperated with a semicolumn. The variable ge works so there is no problem there (tested it with [1,2,3,4] and it worked. What is wrong with this code?

re edit:

found the solution. The array needed to be parsed as a floating number added this code.`

```
for (var i=0; i < lines.length; i++) {
    lines[i]= parseFloat(lines[i]);
    }


findSum(document.getElementById("inp").value.split(";"), ge);
```

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function powerset(arr) {
    var ps = [[]];
    for (var i=0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0, len = ps.length; j < len; j++) {
            ps.push(ps[j].concat(arr[i]));
        }
    }
    return ps;
}

function sum(arr) {
    var total = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
        total += arr[i];
    return total
}

function findSum(numbers, targetSum) {
    var numberSets = powerset(numbers);
    for (var i=0; i < numberSets.length; i++) {
        var numberSet = numberSets[i]; 
        if (sum(numberSet) == targetSum)
            document.getElementById("outp").value=document.getElementById("outp").value+ numberSet +"\n"; 
    }
}

function main()
{

ge= document.getElementById("getal").value;
findSum([1,1,0.5,0.1,0.2,0.2], ge);


}


</script>
</head>
<body>

<input type="button" onclick="main()" value="tel" /><input type="text" id="getal" /><br>
input<br><textarea id="inp"  ></textarea><br>
output<br><textarea id="outp" ></textarea><br>
document.getElementById("inp").value.split(";")
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Homework questions should be tagged as homework. Please edit/update the tags on your question.

Comment: This is not homework as explained below. ;)

Comment: Can no one explain to me how it comes document.getElementById("inp").value.split(";") cqn't be used as a parameter? I have also tried defining the array fist://lines = [[]];
lines = document.getElementById("inp").value.split(",");// using lines as parameter

Comment: Ok. I found the answer to my previous comment. Thanks again for the support Cheeken :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

More concretely, you're looking for a particular sum of each set in the [power set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set) of your collection of numbers.

You can accomplish this with the following bit of code.

```
function powerset(arr) {
    var ps = [[]];
    for (var i=0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0, len = ps.length; j < len; j++) {
            ps.push(ps[j].concat(arr[i]));
        }
    }
    return ps;
}

function sum(arr) {
    var total = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
        total += arr[i];
    return total
}

function findSum(numbers, targetSum) {
    var numberSets = powerset(numbers);
    for (var i=0; i < numberSets.length; i++) {
        var numberSet = numberSets[i]; 
        if (sum(numberSet) == targetSum)
            return numberSet;
    }
}
```

Example invocation:

```
>> findSum([1,2,3,4,5],6)
[1, 2, 3]
>> findSum([1,2,3,4,5],0)
[]
>> findSum([1,2,3,4,5],11)
[1, 2, 3, 5]
```

If you'd like to collect all of the subsets whose sum is the value (rather than the first one, as implemented above) you can use the following method.

```
function findSums(numbers, targetSum) {
    var sumSets = [];
    var numberSets = powerset(numbers);
    for (var i=0; i < numberSets.length; i++) {
        var numberSet = numberSets[i]; 
        if (sum(numberSet) == targetSum)
            sumSets.push(numberSet);
    }
    return sumSets;
}
```

Example invocation:

```
>> findSums([1,2,3,4,5],5);
[[2,3],[1,4],[5]]
>> findSums([1,2,3,4,5],0);
[[]]
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. I'll try this tomorrow. By the way, I wanted this code because I am a public accountant. And sometimes a client reverses a couple  of amounts in one booking, without any comment. This will make it a lot easier to see what bookings have been reversed.

Comment: I tried your code. It apears to be working. I only have one remark question. What if multiple sub sets of your power set added up result in the number you are looking for, e.g.:findSum([1,2,3,4,5],6)
can result [1,2,3] but also [2,4] or [1,5]

Comment: @PieterjanVanDam I've amended my answer to address your question.  If my response is useful, please consider upvoting or accepting it.  Thanks.

Comment: the best solution so far I found in 2021 :-)

Comment: Also the best solution so far in 2022. My goal was to sum each combination of the array and after that found the minimum value that cannot create by the combination and Powerset was the better answer.