# All possibilities that are less than X using only Y numbers?

Tags: javascript, arrays, math, numbers, combinations

Say I have these numbers: [2, 25, 37, 54, 54, 76, 88, 91, 99] (these are random)

And I need to find all combinations of those numbers that are less than 100. Not all numbers have to be used in these combinations. Examples: 2, 2+25+37, 54+25

How can I achieve this in JavaScript?

Thanks

Comment: Sounds like homework :) What have you tried?

Comment: I'm curious to see the most efficient algorithm here.

Comment: @adamb it's not homework. And yes I've tried :(

Comment: Post the code you have tried

Comment: @zombio Fair enough. This has the traits of a typical HW question posted to SO though in that: **1.** The example seems like a classic _discrete mathematics 101_ problem. **2.** There's no code posted. **3.** You haven't expressed the slighted indication that you understand what the solution will entail.

Comment: What constitutes a "combination"?  Is it always the sum of some subset of the list?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So if you have an array of numbers:

```
var arr = [2, 25, 37, 54, 54, 76, 88, 91, 99]
```

First filter the array to just that which is less than 100

```
var filtered = arr.filter(function(val){ return val < 100; });
```

Now you need to find the power set of those numbers.

It looks like there's a sample of code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12020070/352552) that will accomplish that.

Excerpt

```
function powerset(arr) {
    var ps = [[]];
    for (var i=0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0, len = ps.length; j < len; j++) {
            ps.push(ps[j].concat(arr[i]));
        }
    }
    return ps;
}
```

So you'd take

```
var powerSet = powerset(filtered);
```

And as some sugar, you could format the result nicely with join

```
console.log('{' + powerSet.join('}{') + '}');
```

or if you really want it output as a set of all sets, this would technically be more correct :)

```
console.log('{ {' + powerSet.join('}{') + '} }');
```

Here's a [**WORKING DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/wdhDy/)

---

EDIT

Sorry, you want the set of all sets whose **sum** is less than 100.  kennebec is right.  Ditch the filtering first step, and then modify the powerset method thus, using reduce to quickly see if an array's sum is less than 100:

```
function powerset(arr) {
    var ps = [[]];
    for (var i=0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0, len = ps.length; j < len; j++) {
            var arrCandidate = ps[j].concat(arr[i]);
            if (arrCandidate.reduce(function(p, c){ return p + c; }) < 100)
                ps.push(arrCandidate);
        }
    }
    return ps;
}
```

Here's an [**UPDATED DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/wdhDy/5/)

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware of the term "power set" which was key to solving this problem. I was also able to find a good example [here](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Power_set#CoffeeScript).

Comment: Note that this does not function correctly if negative numbers are allowed in the set.

Comment: @kennebec - how so?  I don't see how, and I tested it and it doesn't look wrong.

Comment: BTW, I phrased my question badly, I meant I only wanted possibilities whos SUM is less than 100. But with your solution it's easy to add that last step.

Comment: In your updated demo you forgot the `< 100` check. Fixed in version http://jsfiddle.net/wdhDy/8/

Answer (score 6):

This is a modified version of the [Subset sum problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem). Taking the power set is the brute force solution, and while simple, is inefficient for large lists, taking O(2^N) time. Subset-sum is NP-complete, so you can't solve it in less than exponential time, but if you divide and conquer, you can solve it faster in the average case (but not the worst case)<sup>1</sup>. What you do is, divide the array into two halves and run the powerset function (from Adam's answer) on each half, except you save the sum of the array with the array (in fact, saving the sum of the array creates a huge performance boost even if you don't split the array, as it lets you eliminate lots of redundant addition):

```
var sum = ps[j].sum + arr[i] //huge optimization! don't redo all the addition
if (sum < 100) { //don't include this check if negative numbers are allowed
    arrCandidate.sum = sum;
    ps.push(arrCandidate);
}
```

Then, you sort each half's power set by the sum, sorting in opposite directions

```
ps1.sort(function(b,a){return a.sum-b.sum;});
ps2.sort(function(a,b){return a.sum-b.sum;});
```

Now, you can go through the two lists and return each combination of arrays whose total sum is less than 100:

```
var pos1 = 0;
var pos2 = -1;
while (pos1 < ps1.length) {
    var arr1 = ps1[pos1];
    while (pos2 + 1 < ps2.length && ps2[pos2+1].sum+arr1.sum < 100) {
        pos2++;
    }
    for (var i = pos2; i >= 0; i--) {
        result.push(arr1.concat(ps2[i]));
    }
    pos1++;
}
```

[Working benchmark comparing this to a non-splitting solution](http://jsfiddle.net/wdhDy/13/)

1. The decision version of this solution (which tells you, is there a solution?) runs in O(2^(N/2)) time. I expect this runs in O(2^(N/2)) if there are O(1) solutions, and O(2^N) time (the same as unoptimized) in the worst case where every subset is a solution. In my tests, it is faster by factors of 2-5 on lists of size 20-50 of random numbers from 0 to 99 (Speedup is proportional to size, but I am unsure of by what formula).

Comment: That's incredibly cool.  I don't have the time to really pick through that, but it's a really interesting optimization idea.  +1

Comment: Cool, but surely for bounded input numbers (like in the example - not exceeding 100) dynamic programming solution will be much faster.

Comment: @ciamej If you think you have a better answer, post it as an answer.

Comment: @Saposhiente on second thought, the question is to find all the combinations, not only the number of them. I missed that. Then probably it's not possible to get any better complexity...

Comment: With `O(2^(N/2))` you refer to the average runtime complexity, right? You would still have to compute `O(2^N)` subsets in the worst case, when all elements add up to less than X.

Comment: @le_m You're right, `O(2^(N/2))` is for the decision problem (is there a solution or not?). I've further optimized it and now tested it; it is in fact faster in the average case (though I'm not sure by how much asymptotically).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get only unique combinations you can try something like this...
[***jsFiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/GKDev/Tm4Pj/6/)

```
(function () {
    "use strict";
    var numbers = [2, 25, 37, 54, 54, 76, 88, 91, 99],
        combinations = [];

    (function () {
        var temp = [],
            len = numbers.length,
            sum = 0;

        for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            temp.length = 0;
            sum = numbers[i];

            if (sum < 100) {
                temp.push(sum);
                add(temp);

                for (var j = 0; j < len; j++) {
                    if (numbers[j] >= 100 || i === j) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    sum += numbers[j];

                    if (sum < 100) {
                        temp.push(numbers[j]);
                        add(temp);
                    } else {
                        sum -= numbers[j];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }());

    function add(val) {
        var contains = false,
            temp = null;

        val.sort(function (a, b) {
            return a - b;
        });

        temp = val.join(" ");
        if (combinations.length === 0) {
            combinations.push(temp.split(" "));
            return;
        }

        for (var i = 0; i < combinations.length; i++) {
            if (combinations[i].join(" ") === temp) {
                contains = true;
            }
        }
        if (!contains) {
            combinations.push(temp.split(" "));
        }
    }
}());
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a recursive approach, that also applies to only non-negative array elements:

```
function subset_sum( list, upper_bound )
{
  if( list.length == 1 ) return list[0] < upper_bound ? [list] : [];
  var new_list = list.slice(0); // copy list
  var elem = new_list.pop();
  var combo = elem < upper_bound ? [[elem]] : []; // A
  if( combo.length )
  {
    var lists = subset_sum( new_list, upper_bound-elem ); // B
    combo = combo.concat( lists.map(function(a) { return a.concat(elem); }) );
  }
  return combo.concat(subset_sum( new_list, upper_bound )); // C
}

var arr = [2, 25, 37, 54, 54, 76, 88, 91, 99];
var combos = subset_sum(arr,100);
```

Here's the jfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bceHr/4/

The base case is the single-element list, where the answer is itself if and only if the element is less than the upper bound.

The recursive step is divided into 3 mutually exclusive and complete cases, marked A, B, and C above:

- (A) The last element is a singleton set if and only if it is less than the upper_bound.
- (B) All other subsets which *include* the last element are counted, by recusively applying the function to the list omitting the element, and a new upper_bound decreased by that element.
- (C) All other subsets which *exclude* the last element are counted, by recursively applying the function to the list using the same upper_bound.

Lastly, there are 26 such combinations. Since 54 is included twice, it is repeated in the output as well:

> [[99],[91],[2,91],[88],[2,88],[76],[2,76],[54],[37,54],[2,37,54],[25,54],[2,25,54],[2,54],[54],[37,54],[2,37,54],[25,54],[2,25,54],[2,54],[37],[25,37],[2,25,37],[2,37],[25],[2,25],[2]]